# Why is my Triggered AzureWebJob being triggered multiple times

Tags: azure, cron, azure-webjobs

I saw [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35659114/why-is-timertrigger-in-azurewebjob-is-being-triggered-twice) and I am getting a similar, but different effect. I have used the information from [Scheduling Azure WebJobs with cron expressions](http://blog.amitapple.com/post/2015/06/scheduling-azure-webjobs/#.VuFM39BhLBY) and looking at the triggered WebJob api I get:

1. A single trigger on the hour, which has `latest_run.triggered` set to "External - ".
2. Multiple (> 10) runs at 10 past the hour, which have `latest_run.triggered` set to "Schedule - * 10 * * * *".

The logs show that it is run multiple times (like 19 times!) when run at 10 past the hour. Here is a snippet from the end of the job_scheduler.log file (I have shortened it. The last two invocations of the WebJob ran 16 and 19 times respectively).

```
[03/10/2016 10:10:52 > bdda8b: SYS INFO] WebJob invoked
[03/10/2016 10:10:52 > bdda8b: SYS INFO] Next schedule expected in 00:00:00.2973642
[03/10/2016 10:10:53 > bdda8b: SYS INFO] Next schedule expected in 00:00:00.5786066
[03/10/2016 10:10:54 > bdda8b: SYS INFO] WebJob invoked
[03/10/2016 10:10:54 > bdda8b: SYS INFO] Next schedule expected in 00:00:00.4536019
[03/10/2016 10:10:55 > bdda8b: SYS INFO] WebJob invoked
[03/10/2016 10:10:55 > bdda8b: SYS INFO] Next schedule expected in 00:00:00.4067190
[03/10/2016 10:10:56 > bdda8b: SYS INFO] Next schedule expected in 00:00:00.7034940
[03/10/2016 10:10:57 > bdda8b: SYS INFO] WebJob invoked
[03/10/2016 10:10:57 > bdda8b: SYS INFO] Next schedule expected in 00:00:00.5629458
[03/10/2016 10:10:58 > bdda8b: SYS INFO] Next schedule expected in 00:00:00.0187612
[03/10/2016 10:11:00 > bdda8b: SYS INFO] WebJob invoked
[03/10/2016 10:11:00 > bdda8b: SYS INFO] Next schedule expected in 00:59:00.9405909
[03/10/2016 10:27:57 > bdda8b: SYS INFO] Scheduling WebJob with * 10 * * * * next schedule expected in 00:42:03.7574703
```

Note: The job_scheduler file does not show the run at 0 past the hour run. However the Azure WebJob Scheduler says it ran the job at that time.

If I trigger the WebJob manually inside the Azure portal then it only runs once (according to the Azure WebJob Dashboard), so it seems like the scheduler is doing something funny.

My WebJob is part of a Web Service and is deployed with the Web Site using Publish. I have a triggered WebJob designed to run once every hour. My WebJob `setting.job` file looks like this:

```
{
   //This will run every hour at 10 minutes past the hour
   "schedule": "* 10 0-23 * * *"
}
```

and my webjob-publish-settings.json file (which I believe isn't used any more) looks like this:

```
{
 "$schema": "http://schemastore.org/schemas/json/webjob-publish-settings.json",
 "webJobName": "PrintProcessorWebJob",
 "startTime": "2014-06-23T00:00:00+08:00",
 "endTime": "2020-01-01T00:00:00+01:00",
 "jobRecurrenceFrequency": "Hour",
 "interval": 1,
 "runMode": "Scheduled"
}
```

I *think* this is a new problem, but in trying to diagnose it I deleted the existing WebJob so I lost the old logs. I do know that the rules of WebJobs changed during development and maybe I didn't update things properly.

Comment: You shouldn't lose logs if you maintain the same Webjob name and Azure Storage connection string on the JobHostConfiguration. It is indeed weird, did you check on the logs when it auto-detects the Functions if it might have detected more than 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary issue is that your cron expression is incorrect. `* 10 * * * *` means "Run every second for one minute at 10 minutes past the hour". Instead, you want `0 10 * * * *`.

The secondary issue is that you seem to have remnants of the Azure scheduler which you need to get rid of. Try going to the Azure Portal under scheduler, and delete anything that shouldn't be there. And your `webjob-publish-settings.json` should look like [this](https://github.com/davidebbo-test/WebAppWithWebJobsVS/blob/5471db17dc3ba9ccfc632dde3feecdf69c5cf853/MyTriggeredWebJob/Properties/webjob-publish-settings.json).